# Literature to support effect size over significance

Tags: statistical-significance, references, effect-size

In a large sample ($N = 3,265,506$ for my study) tests are always significant. Is there an article in the literature I can cite to justify using effect size instead of significance testing?

Comment: For what purpose are you testing?  (There is an *enormous* amount of literature on this, by the way; my question concerns whether any of it is really relevant to *your* problem.)

Comment: A starting place is some of the ***References*** and most of the ***Further Reading*** at the bottom [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance). There's also some information in the references [here](http://www.statisticshell.com/docs/effectsizes.pdf), but what, exactly, you need would be most easily addressed with more information, just as whuber suggested.